# How to add a loop to an SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im newer to SQL and I've been tasked with refactoring this bit of code. When I look at this, I want to throw up.

I'm trying to modify this sproc so that it can return any number of columns rather than a fixed number. Here's what it looks like now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [frsuser].[usp_report_UnitFeatureHeaders]
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #features (SortOrder INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                            ,label  NVARCHAR(20)  )
INSERT INTO #features (label)
    SELECT label FROM UnitAttributeDefinition order by tab_sort_order

SELECT   'UnitID'                                                   AS UnitID
        ,'UnitName'                                                 AS UnitName
        ,'UnitAddress'                                              AS UnitAddress
        ,'RateUnitType'                                             AS RateUnitType
        ,'TaxDistrict'                                              AS TaxDistrict
        ,'ContractType'                                             AS ContractType
        ,'InactiveUnit'                                             AS InactiveUnit
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = 1) AS Feature01
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = 2) AS Feature02
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = 3) AS Feature03
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = 4) AS Feature04
        .......
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = 100) AS Feature100
    DROP TABLE #features
END
```

Here's the idea of what I want it to look like.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [frsuser].[usp_report_UnitFeatureHeaders]
@numberOfFeatures Int = 100
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #features (SortOrder INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                            ,label  NVARCHAR(20)  )
INSERT INTO #features (label)
    SELECT label FROM UnitAttributeDefinition order by tab_sort_order

DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @featureName NVARCHAR (20) = 'Feature';


SELECT   'UnitID'                                                   AS UnitID
        ,'UnitName'                                                 AS UnitName
        ,'UnitAddress'                                              AS UnitAddress
        ,'RateUnitType'                                             AS RateUnitType
        ,'TaxDistrict'                                              AS TaxDistrict
        ,'ContractType'                                             AS ContractType
        ,'InactiveUnit'                                             AS InactiveUnit
        (WHILE @counter < @numberOfFeatures
            BEGIN 
                SET @featureName = 'Feature' + @counter;
                (SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = @counter) 
            END 
        ) AS @featureName

DROP TABLE #features
```

END

Is such a refactor even possible? and if so, what would it look like?

Comment: you can only achieve this using a dynamic sql and STUFF for your feature columns

Comment: Whenever I hear LOOP in a SQL question, I want to throw up.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to build a dynamic sql query, concatenate all the labels you need with a while loop and then run the query with **sp_executesql** it should be something like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [frsuser].[usp_report_UnitFeatureHeaders]
@numberOfFeatures Int = 100
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #features (SortOrder INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                            ,label  NVARCHAR(20)  )
INSERT INTO #features (label)
    SELECT label FROM UnitAttributeDefinition order by tab_sort_order

DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @featureName NVARCHAR (20) = 'Feature';


-- 
DECLARE @SQL_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @SQL_QUERY =
' 
SELECT   ''UnitID''                                                   AS UnitID
        ,''UnitName''                                                 AS UnitName
        ,''UnitAddress''                                              AS UnitAddress
        ,''RateUnitType''                                             AS RateUnitType
        ,''TaxDistrict''                                              AS TaxDistrict
        ,''ContractType''                                             AS ContractType
        ,''InactiveUnit''                                             AS InactiveUnit '

-- ADD FEATURES TO YOUR QUERY

WHILE @counter <= @numberOfFeatures

BEGIN 

    SET @SQL_QUERY = CAST((SELECT ISNULL(label,'') FROM #features WHERE SortOrder = @counter) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' AS Feauture '+ CAST(@counter as varchar(4)) + ' '
END


SET @SQL_QUERY = 'FROM  TABLE ....' --END OF THE QUERY STATEMENT

DROP TABLE #features    

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @query
```

i think you should get @numberoffeautures with a Count of the table that contains all the labels and not as paramater for the Stored procedure

Comment: Upvoted, but one small thing is your counter starts at zero, so you'll end up with the first feature being Feature0, and selecting SortOrder = 0, and so forth. I think OP's question assumed it would start at 1.

Comment: You are rigth, Just fixed it